# Ajax webservice does not work in remote machines

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services

I have a webservice written in c# used by a Windows phone cliente and working.

So i develop a html5/jquery to use that same asmx service and Works!

When i try to access this html page from a remote machine(other than the host for the pages and servisse) it fails.

is there any special configuration for this scenario?

The only difference is, changed from localhost in the address of the ajax call to webservice to the fixed ip of the host, same i did to publish to the phone device.

Here is the code

```
       $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8000/services/webservice.asmx/RetornaPedidoPorMesa",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data: { NumeroMesa: parseInt(querystring("numeroMesa")), 
         CodigoSeguranca: parseInt(querystring("codigo")) },
        success: function (response) {

            var xml = $(response);
            if (xml.find("Retorno").text() != "") {
                var list = $("#pedido").find('ul');
                $("#ulPedido li").remove();

                list.append("<li>Voçê não tem permissão para acessar o pedido</li>");
            } else {

                if (xml.find("Total") != "") {
                    var list = $("#pedido").find('ul');
                    $("#ulPedido li").remove();

                    list.append("<li>" + "Mesa  " + querystring("numeroMesa") + "   -   " + "R$ " + xml.find("Total").first().text() + "</li>");
                }
                if (xml.find("Items") != "") {
                    if (xml.find("RetornoItems") != "") {
                        var list = $("#produtos").find('ul');
                        $("#ulProdutos li").remove();
                        $(xml.find("RetornoItems")).each(function myfunction() {
                            if (parseInt($(this).find("Quantidade").first().text()) > 0)
                                list.append("<li>" + $(this).find("Descricao").text() + "<div style='float:right\;margin-left:30px;margin-top:10px'>" + parseInt($(this).find("Quantidade").first().text()) + " x R$ " + $(this).find("ValorUnitario").first().text() + " = R$ " + $(this).find("Total").first().text() + "</div></li>");

                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("erro de acesso ao serviço.");
        }
    });
```

Any help? thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you ruled out the cause being the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)?

Comment: Are you able to `ping` to the machine running your `webservice`?

Comment: Yes i can ping, actually the windows phone device can access the same service, so no firewall and webserver issues.